# Как сделать перенос строки в xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

У меня есть xml данные: `<docName>document1.pdf,document2.pdf,document3.pdf</docName>`

Мне нужно в шаблоне сделать перенос строки вот так:
`<docName>
document1.pdf,
document2.pdf,
document3.pdf
</docName>`

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

У меня не работает тег `<br />` вот здесь:

```
<xsl:variable name='newline'>
     <xsl:text>&lt;br/&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

Это вызов из xml файла:

```
<xsl:variable name="newtext">
<xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="docName" />
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="','" />
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$newline" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$newtext"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="Replace">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="target"/>
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains( $string, $target)">
                <xsl:call-template name="Replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat(substring-before($string, $target), $value, substring-after($string, $target))"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="target" select="$target"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name='newline'>
        <xsl:text>&lt;br/&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="newtext">
        <xsl:call-template name="Replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="docName" />
            <xsl:with-param name="target" select="','" />
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$newline" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:value-of select="$newtext"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: не работает этот код

Comment: проверил здесь, https://xslttest.appspot.com/  все работает. А если добавить, то выводит сразу как html.
   <xsl:value-of select="$newtext" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

Comment: извините, я изначально не указала, у меня текст выводится на пдф файл. И это код не переносит текст на новую строку

Comment: Это нужно указывать! Как и то что используете xslt 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Нужно отключать "ескейпинг" при выводе. Например так

```
<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;br/&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Можно ли сделать это через variable - да

```
<xsl:value-of select="$newtext" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Если ескейпинг выключен - символы в документ передатутся "как есть" (ну в расшифрованом виде). По умолчанию он включен и символы будут конвертированы `>` в `&gt;` и тому подобное.

Тут подробнее http://xsltdev.ru/xslt/xsl-value-of/

Comment: выходит ошибка где тег br используете

Comment: В первом случае или втором? Я в первом случае строковый литерал пропустил. Поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Как именно делать перенос строки, зависит от того, в какой выходной формат происходит трансформация.

В теге `xsl:output` в атрибуте `method` можно указать значения "xml | html | text".

Вам, очевидно, нужен плоский текст. В нём перевод строки и возврат каретки делаются так:

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;&#xd;</xsl:text>
```

А добавление тега `<br/>` сделает перевод строки в выходных форматах xml и html.

Comment: я этот вариант пробовала использовать, но не работает

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara - в какой **формат** происходит трансформация? Плоский текст или разметка? Этот вариант **работает** с плоским текстом. Ваш вариант работает с xml/html.

Comment: если честно, не понимаю вопроса. Как понять плоский текст или разметка

Comment: После трансформации что получаете: файл `.txt` или файл `.xml`/`.html`? Ну или где вы выполняете трансформацию? Как смотрите результат?

Comment: в .pdf формате выходит

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara - У вас XSL-FO?

Comment: если смотреть на эту запись, получается так  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"

                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                extension-element-prefixes="str"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
                exclude-result-prefixes="fo">

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara - Вот! Это важная информация и её следует указать в вопросе. Используется несколько стадий трансформации, xsl-fo и к тому же xslt второй версии. Ну а я вряд ли помочь смогу.

Comment: что в итоге? это информация даст мне решить проблему? почему не работает это выражение: <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xd;</xsl:text>

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara - это выражение **работает**. Оно вставляет в итоговый текст перенос строки и перевод каретки. Если смотреть результат текстовым редактором, то это видно. Если смотреть результат в веб-браузере, то браузер, конечно же, убирает пробельные символы.

Comment: я вывожу в pdf файл и не работает

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara - технология xslt не может напрямую выводить в pdf. Я понятия не имею, что там дополнительно у вас используется.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант для xsl-fo и 2.0 сильно проще.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:template match="docName">        
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',')">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />  
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```